# How to catch rejected error in var socket = new WebSocket(url) ?

Tags: javascript, html

In backend,  i define a custom code 509, how can i catch the code in js browser?

var socket = new WebSocket(url);
socket.onopen = function(event) {}

Answer (score 0):

On client-side/browser:-

```
var socket = new WebSocket(url);
 socket.onopen = function(event) {
   //the data sent from the server is saved in "event.data"
   console.log(event.data)
}
```

You can take a look with my open source library, it can create websocket server, handle message, and auto reconnect easily. It works for both server-side and client-side. Take you time to check the example directory in the [github](https://github.com/jefftham/wsm).

[wsm - WebSocket Manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wsm)

Comment: while, in the server side, it limits the max count of websocket connections number, if it reaches 4, in the handshake ,returns custom response code 509, i just want to catch the code, onopen can't help me

Comment: what library do you use? The function name may be different.  On browser, we use onopen.  on node.js back-end, some library use on('connection', function(){})